# How to calculate an expression in jQuery templates

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have data from an external JSON source that I want to display using jQUery templates. There are 2 integer variables. I need to divide one by another inside my jQuery Templates template string. Now template string looks like this:

```
templateNumbers="${a}, ${b}"
```

I want not just to show these two numbers, but show a result of a dividing one by another.

JSON looks like this one:

```
[
    {
        a: 5,
        b: 1,
    },
    {
        a: 7,
        b: 2,
    }

]
```

I tried to use "${a/b}" but it doesn't work, may be because I have an array and may be I should play with $item?
How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Are there any other details that make your sample different than this one: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/CRUrU/ ?  For example, is your data a javascript object or a JSON string?  If ${a}, ${b} was really working for you, then it would have to be an object already.

Comment: I think I have just did a typo somewhere. I rewrote this code from scratch and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
${a/b}
```

According to this [intro page](http://www.borismoore.com/2010/09/introducing-jquery-templates-1-first.html), you can have any expression in ${}

Answer (score 0):

Make the division before and add another variable to send to the template with the result.